# Merging sql row groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

My applications splits a single row data into different row chunks which are always in sorted order of startdate.

Where rowpart = 0 is the start and rowpart=2 is always the end
        rowpart=1 is the middle part,which can be repeated n no of times.

I need to return row in such form like startdate of rowpart=0 and enddate of rowpart=2(if present or else return enddate for rowpart )

- Rowpart = 0 is the start of new row chunk
- Rowpart = 2 is always the end of the chunk

Chunks can be spread across different dates.

```
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| Id  |        startdate        |         enddate         | rowpart |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 100 | 2016-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 2016-11-30 01:00:00.000 |        0 |
| 100 | 2016-11-30 02:00:00.000 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00.000 |        1 |
| 100 | 2016-11-30 10:00:00.000 | 2016-12-01 00:00:00.000 |        0 |
| 100 | 2016-12-01 02:00:00.000 | 2016-12-01 02:30:00.000 |        1 |
| 100 | 2016-12-01 10:00:00.000 | 2016-12-01 10:30:00.000 |        1 |
| 100 | 2016-12-01 16:00:00.000 | 2016-12-01 16:30:00.000 |        2 |
| 101 | 2016-12-11 10:00:00.000 | 2016-12-11 10:30:00.000 |        0 |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

So the above table should return:

```
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Id  |        startdate        |         enddate         |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 100 | 2016-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 2016-11-30 03:00:00.000 |
| 100 | 2016-12-30 10:00:00.000 | 2016-12-01 16:30:00.000 |
| 101 | 2016-12-11 10:00:00.000 | 2016-12-11 10:30:00.000 |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As per SO you should respond something to the question you have asked..if it helps you any of the answer ..do the upvote ..happy coding

Comment: I did reply to answers posted below and i am still trying to solve this.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: Shouldn't your output's second row start at `2016-11-30 10:00:00.000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
;WITH temp
AS
(
SELECT  Id, startdate,enddate,rowpart,
        --Find out First Record
        CASE WHEN rowpart=0
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS is_first,
        --Find out Last Record, Check if next rowpart is 0 or NULL:
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(LEAD(rowpart) OVER (ORDER BY Id, startdate),0) = 0 --Check if next rowpart is 0 or NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS is_last
FROM    @tab
)

SELECT  DISTINCT
        Id,
        CASE WHEN is_first = 1
            THEN startdate
            ELSE LAG(startdate) OVER (ORDER BY Id, startdate) 
        END AS startdate,
        CASE WHEN is_last = 1
            THEN enddate
            ELSE LEAD(enddate) OVER (ORDER BY Id, startdate) 
        END AS enddate
FROM    temp 
WHERE   is_first = 1 OR is_last = 1
ORDER BY Id, startdate
```

What i try to do here: Inside the CTE i mark the first and the last record for each sequence. If rowpart=0 --> it's the first record. If the next record is null or the the rowpart of the next record is 0 then we have the last record.

So when querying the CTE we can eliminate the "records in between". What remains are 1 or 2 records per sequence (the first and the last, in some cases this is the same record).

Then we replace `startdate`  with the startdate of the first record of the sequence and `enddate` with the enddate of the last record of the sequence.

Eliminate duplicate values with `DISTINCT` and you get the desired output.

This is a dirty piece of SQL, but at least it works ;-)

If you didn't know SQL Servers `LEAD` and `LAG`function to access previous or following row values check this out: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

Comment: Has a problem with 'incomplete' sequences.  If, for a single `id`, the rowparts are `0,1,1,2,  2,  0,1,2,  0` then the 'second sequence' and the 'fourth sequence' are only one entry long, but your use of `LEAD(enddate)` assumes there will always be at least two entries.  In such a case your logic would get the enddate from the first row of the next sequence.  Realistically, a sequence of just one row may only happen as the last entry for an `id` (see OP's last row for `id` 101), but it "may" be possible "mid-stream"...

Comment: No, `LEAD(enddate)` is only used, if is_last <> 0. 
So "the one-row-sequences" will get is_last = 1, because the LEAD(rowpart) is 0 (2. sequence) or null (4. sequence)!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @CeOnSql. Considering only rowpart=0 and not grouping or depending on date. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Check This. using CTE and Joins :

```
        with CTE as
        (
          select distinct *,
          CASE WHEN COALESCE(LEAD(rowpart) OVER (ORDER BY Id, startdate),0) = 0 
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0 
          end as RN2
          from #table
        )          
        select distinct bb.id,bb.startdate,aa.enddate from 
         (
            select C2.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(  ORDER BY id, startdate ) RN3              
            from CTE C2 where RN2= 1 
          )  aa 
          join
          ( 
             select distinct *,
             ROW_NUMBER()OVER(  ORDER BY id, startdate ) RN3 
              from CTE c1  where rowpart=0
          ) bb on aa.RN3=bb.RN3
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Comment: This won't work for as the id (eg id=100) is repeated. An id can have multiple chunks . So this returns multiple values as it joins on id

Comment: Check Code Updated.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot.The problem is b.rowpart=2,which always joins to the last rowpart. There can be a case when there is no rowpart=2.

Comment: @NavedMir Again I have updated working code.  as per your input table and expected output.

Comment: @MatBailie . You are right. Thank for info. use changed input table and i am still working on old one provided input table. Now i have corrected code with result.

Comment: @MatBailie thnk for new era of this.  Code Edited again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple `Group by` is all you need

Try this

```
select Id,min(startdate),max(enddate)
From yourtable
Group by Id,cast(startdate as date)
```

Comment: Thanks man,your query works like a charm. The only problem is what if the chunks are spread across different dates.

Comment: @NavedMir - add that scenario in question. Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: Sorry my bad, sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select 
Id, 
startdate,
 enddate 
from (
    select Id, 
startdate,
 enddate,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE,startdate) ORDER BY startdate DESC  )RN from @Table1
    GROUP BY Id, startdate, enddate)T
WHERE T.RN = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it partitions by startdate and  returns only 1st row, which is not correct for enddate part

Comment: then Add End date also in partition in check but it is giving exact result set what you have posted @NavedMir

Comment: Sir please check the endDate column in the result

Comment: Thanks for your help,but it has the same issue as Prdp's answer. Problem occurs when the chunks are spread across different dates.

Comment: please adopt this code into your requirement . We gave the answer as the question provided . exactly we don't know your business scenario @NavedMir

Comment: i had updated the question, which stated "Chunks can be spread across different dates."

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    your_table_lead AS
(
    SELECT
        your_table.*,
         LAG(rowpart, 1, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                      ORDER BY startdate)    AS last_rowpart,
        LEAD(rowpart, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                      ORDER BY startdate)    AS next_rowpart
    FROM
        your_table
),
    filtered_sorted AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                               ORDER BY startdate)    AS id_seq_num
    FROM
        your_table_lead
    WHERE
                rowpart IN (0, 2)
        OR next_rowpart = 0
        OR last_rowpart = 2
)
SELECT
    id,
    MIN(startdate),
    MAX(enddate)
FROM
    filtered_sorted
GROUP BY
    id,
    id_seq_num - CASE rowpart WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE rowpart END
```

The first steps just try to filter out everything except the first and last entry of each 'group'.  If the rowpart is 0 or 2, the row is included, or if the Next Row's rowpart is 0 then that row is included too (If there isn't a next row, use 0).

Then the 'trick' is to find a way to group up the 'pairs'.

If we have a sequence of `0,2,0,1,0,2,2,0` then what we want is to group them like `a,a,b,b,c,c,d,e`.

That can be done by turning all the 2's into 1's, the deducting the value from the ROW_NUMBER().

`0,2,0,1,0,2,2,0` => `0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0`

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` - `0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0` => `1,1,3,3,5,5,6,8`

So, now we have 5 distinct 'groups', on which we can apply MIN() and MAX().

Comment: Your query return wrong data / multiple entries for  for ID 100 entry.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosdale Seems to work to me.  Exactly what result does it give that it should not?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale Thanks.  `EKSE 0` should have been `ELSE rowpart`.  Doing this on a phone is hard work :)